# MySQL insert or update with nested query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I have a query that need to insert values in a table and update them if the key already exists.

This request is the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1(`id`, `day`, `quantity`, `residue`)
      SELECT
          id,
          SUBDATE(NOW(), 1) as day,
          (
             A SUB QUERY 
          ) as qte,
          (
             ANOTHER SUB QUERY
          ) as r
FROM table2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  quantity=qte, 
  residue=r;
```

This request result in the error `Unknown column 'qte' in 'field list'`
What did I miss ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `VALUES()`:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    quantity = VALUES(quantity), 
    residue = VALUES(residue)
```

How this works is [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> In assignment value expressions in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, you can use the `VALUES(col_name)` function to refer to column values from the `INSERT` portion .

Comment: If I understand correctly the VALUES(column) refers to the existing values not to the new ones from the select so with this i will just keep the same values instead of updating with the new ones.

Comment: @Xiidref: it refers to the "new" values. Further in the documentation: *In other words, VALUES(col_name) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred.*

Comment: Yes after double checking it's my bad sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks you for the answer it work like a charm now!

Comment: this non-standard use of VALUES is deprecated in newer versions of mysql (I think 8.0.19?)  and will give a warning.   there, instead you should add an alias `AS newdata` or some such between the column list and the SELECT and say `=newdata.columnname` in the on duplicate clause